# Assign a value to a $_SESSION variable uppon clicking on a button

Tags: php, session, object

here is the story : I want to transfer an object from a page to an another (let's say from `list.php` to `product_details.php`)

I know you can achieve this using serialisation, and storing your object variable into a `$_SESSION` variable, assuming my product_details.php will load the class to retrieve methods.

However, I don't want to create as many `$_SESSION` variables as I have products in my list.php.

On my list.php, every product have its a href  button that  goes to `product_details` with a $_GET  (like  `<a href="product_details.php?pid=15>` )

I know I could just recreate a new object on my product_details.php with the `$_GET` value and an extra query on the database. I'm learning stuff and trying to handle new approaches.

My page `list.php` have only one object at a time, which is constructed and unset at every row. It can have as many objects as there are products if needed though.

The question is, how could I do (or which language should I use/learn) to make a given `<a href="product_details.php?pid=15">` type button perform the following :

```
$_SESSION['product'] = serialize($objProduct);
```

before it actually jumps to my product_details.php?

Thanks

Comment: Dont bother! Its likely quicker to do another query in the second page code that it is to read the session file form disk. If you are storing session on the database then there is no real reason to store data in the session as a select is basically a select

Comment: assign a variable to a GET array and (re)assign to the session array.

Comment: Oh and as the session is a server side data store you cannot make a button click in the browser effect the session data directly, using any language

Comment: @RiggsFolly OP is "waiting", not me. *ciao*